# MVC Winforms c# nullreferenceexception

Tags: c#, winforms, model-view-controller, nullreferenceexception

I am a nooby trying to learn mvc in C# winforms, but I cant seem to understand why my instance turns null on me.

View Form

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form, ISingleTagProperties
{
   .....        
    PropController _propController;

    public void SetController(PropController controller)
    {      
        _propController = controller;
    }
.....
   private void dataGridView3_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       _propController.updateProperites(dgv);
   }
```

Edit:Calling updateProperties is what gives me the null reference.

Controller PropController class

```
public class PropController
{
     SingleTagProperties _view;

    //constructor
    public PropController(SingleTagProperties view)
    {
        _view = view;
        view.SetController(this);
    }
......
```

View Instance ISingleTagProperties

```
 public interface ISingleTagProperties
{
    void SetController(PropController controller);

    string TagName { get; set; }
    string TagDescription { get; set; }
.....
```

SetController fires and _propController comes out not null, but then further down in the form trying to call a method from the PropController class gives a NullReferenceException saying that _propController is null.

There's probably some basic understanding I am missing somewhere, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: That line is nowhere in the sample code you provided.

Comment: This is barely readable and the line you provide is not in your samples. Please apply existing conventions to help us to read your code: prefix interfaces names with capital `i`, prefix variable names with `_` only if they are private, name your methods with PascalCase.

Comment: @SébastienSevrin He did say "I am a newbie". Be gentle.

Comment: @GaryMcGill Sorry if my comment seemed rude (it does look rude re-reading it ^^)

Comment: @SébastienSevrin I am a self taught so I haven't really taken the time to look into conventional naming. Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence of events must be:

1. The form is created.
2. ...
3. You create the view, passing in the form as a constructor parameter, which sets _propController.

When you create the form, all the other controls likely get created too (usually by a call made in the constructor to a method in the partial class generated for you by the tooling).

This is effectively step 3 above, and I suspect the process of initialising those controls is triggering that event. Because that happens before step 2, _propController is not set.

You might want to put in a null check or other work-around, although having a reference to the controller from the view seems to break the very MVC separation you wanted to achieve.

Comment: Ohh that makes sense adding a null check seems to have solved the problem. I understand how I was structuring events wrong. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong tools for the job...

If you want to learn MVC, use `ASP.NET MVC` `(Model View Controller)`, if you want to learn a design pattern that's suited for desktop / mobile application development, get started with `WPF` and learn `MVVM` `(Model View ViewModel)`.

Here's an excellent resource which you can learn from:

[PluralSight: ASP.NET MVC 5 - Fundamentals](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/pluralsight-aspnet-mvc-5-fundamentals/introduction-and-prerequisites)

Comment: I think mvvm is definitely better suited for what I am trying to do. Thanks for the help

Comment: Your welcome, if you've found that this has answered your question, please choose it as the selected answer. Cheers